# Using Scala with MongoDB - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DBObject

Tags: mongodb, scala

I created a simple project.

"sbt run" works fine.

After I run "sbt package" jar file appears, but it does not work.

```
$ scala target/scala-2.9.2/hello_2.9.2-0.1.jar
```

The following error occures:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DBObject
```

Here are my files:

Hello.scala

```
package greeter
object Hello extends App {
    import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
    val mongoClient =  MongoClient()
    println("Connected to MongoDB")
    val collection = mongoClient("test")("foo")
    val doc = MongoDBObject("msg" -> "Hi from Scala!")
    collection.insert(doc)
    println("Doc inserted");
}
```

build.sbt

```
name := "hello"

mainClass := Some("greeter.Hello")

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb" % "casbah_2.9.2" % "2.5.0"

resolvers += "snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

resolvers += "releases"  at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the library dependencies to your classpath when running the `scala` command. Assuming you download all the libraries jars in a lib folder, you will need to run:

```
scala -cp "lib/*" target/scala-2.9.2/hello_2.9.2-0.1.jar
```

In build.sbt, use the following setting to automatically download all the jars in a lib_managed folder:

```
retrieveManaged := true
```

Comment: Thank you. So I need to copy all jar files from lib_managed folder to lib folder? Is there a simple command for that, or do I need to use some tricky bash command? And how can I combine all those jars in one?

Comment: Actually you can just use the lib_managed folder directly:

    `scala -cp "lib_managed/*" target/scala-2.9.2/hello_2.9.2-0.1.jar`

Or you can copy the whole folder with:

    `cp -rf lib_managed lib`

Comment: I tried `-cp "lib_managed/*"`, but it does not work. The same error occures `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DBObject`. Than I copied all jars to lib filder and used `-cp "lib/*"`, and it works.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that the jars are not at the root of lib_managed. The best way to make a clean `lib` dir with all the jars is to create an empty lib dir: `mkdir lib` and then copy the jars: `find lib_managed/ -name *.jar -exec cp {} lib/ \;`